# Warum "niemand" anstelle "niemandem" in der Paraphrase "Ich nehme niemand einen Platz weg" einer Behauptung Lahms

Tags: pronoun, sentence-structure

Dank des Hauptitels auf dieser [Seite der FIFA](http://de.fifa.com/worldcup/news/y=2014/m=6/news=lahm-ich-nehme-niemand-einen-platz-weg-2367111.html), und zwar

> *Lahm: "Ich nehme niemand einen Platz weg"*,

habe ich gerade erfahren, dass man auch [*niemand* anstelle *niemandem*](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/niemand) –und eigentlich auch anstelle der Akkusativform *niemanden*, allerdings nicht anstelle der Genitivform *niemand(e)s*– sagen darf. Wann ist der Ersatz angebracht? (Ich vermute nicht immer)

Comment: hast Du einen Link der belegt, dass das korrekt ist? Mir stößt es völlig auf, und ohne jemanden anprangern zu wollen haben bisher viele Fußballer ihre "eigenen" Formulierungen gehabt, die nicht immer korrekt waren..

Comment: Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/niemand) ist _niemand_ sowohl für Nominativ, Dativ und Akkusativ zulässig. Leider ist nicht beschrieben wann welche Form üblich ist. Mir waren bis jetzt für Dativ / Akkusativ auch nur _niemandem_ / _niemanden_ bekannt. Im Beispiel b. werden beide Formen verwendet.

Comment: @christian.s Aber natürlich ;) Normalerweise gucke ich mal hier http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/niemand. Siehste? Ich füge den Link dem Text hinzu.

Comment: Umgangssprachlich ist das für meine Ohren völlig in Ordnung.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die unflektierte Form [scheint nicht generell falsch zu sein](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-jemand3.html) (siehe auch [diese umfangreiche Q/A in grammis 2.0](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/?v_kat=&v_id=4332)). Ich würde der Klarheit halber die flektierte Dativform bevorzugen - allemal in der Schriftsprache.

[Wörtlich sagte Philipp Lahm übrigens](https://web.archive.org/web/20140817211326/http://www.kicker.de:80/news/fussball/wm/wmteams/1353286/video_philipp-lahm---ich-nehme-niemandem-den-platz-weg.html): „Ich glaub' ich nehm' keinem Spieler einen Platz weg.“

Comment: (+1) Dank deines Links ist Lahm erlöst – der Verfasser des Artikels aber nicht. (Dementsprechend habe ich den Titel geändert).  Die Tatsache, dass er Verfasser ist, lässt mich vermuten, dass er, na ja, schreiben kann – viel besser als ich eine Fremdsprache lesen kann. Daher die Frage.

Comment: der Link lautet übrigens "video_philipp-lahm---ich-nehme-niemandem-den-platz-weg.html" - niemandem..

Comment: Der Linktitel orientiert sich am Seitentitel, man findet für beide Varianten reichlich Treffer - manche Redaktionen haben sich wohl ähnliche Gedanken wie [c.p.](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/13478/392) gemacht...